# Noob jQuery problem: how to access an custom object's settings

Tags: jquery

im currently learning jQuery and have ran into a problem. I am trying to use the liteAccordion library (found here: http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/)

i want to have a button to hide the "accordion" but since it has autoPlay, i get a bunch of error. I was wondering how i can temporarily turn off the autoPlay. 
ie: how can i modify the autoPlay value of the object. The object is created as follows:

```
$('#mainNavigation').liteAccordion({
    onActivate : function() {
        this.find('figcaption').fadeOut();
    },
        slideCallback : function() {
        this.find('figcaption').fadeIn();
    },
    autoPlay : true,
    pauseOnHover : true,
    theme : 'colorful',
    rounded : true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing the main div, which lite accordion uses;using jquery hide
for example: you can use
$('#one').hide() to hide the div on lite accordion page.
http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/ (the div which is the main container for accordion ,has an id ="one")

or refer the accordion while you create, using a variable
     `myAccordion = $('#two').liteAccordion();`

now use jquery functions on the variable
      `$(myAccordion).hide();` etc

Comment: thank you for that very fast reply! but sadly it did not fix my errors. The slides are still on autoplay and still showing errors because "$group is undefined" :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out how to turn off the auto play, instead of hiding it the normal way you can try to hide it by setting `position:absolute` to a value way off screen like:

```
$('#mainNavigation').css({ position:'absolute', left:'-99999em' });
```

Since it's using absolute positioning you won't get any unwanted scroll bars.